# The element 'system.web' has invalid child element 'defaultDocument'

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I'm training my web.config to recognize what the best default file is. According to my host it's supposed to look like in the listing below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>

    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Defalut.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <machineKey/>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that VS2012 (Express) marks it blue and claims the error in the subject. First i thought that i could upload it as it is and by brute force make the server to like the file but it then got angry and spat out the following

*HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.*

As i read the error message it says that: *"The configuration section 'defaultDocument' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration."*

I've done my homework and found the article below but due to the limitation in my situation (e.g. i need to manually upload the web.config file and i can't run any scripts on the server of my hosting company), it was to no avail.

How do i kill this little problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Defalut.aspx" is a definite yellow flag.

SUGGESTION:

1. Just create a new dummy project with MSVS2012 (I don't have a copy handy, so I can't help you at the moment)
2. Cut and paste the auto-generated "web.config" into your project and verify that it works.
   If it doesn't, make *ONLY* those *MINIMAL* changes needed to get a clean compile/execute.
3. Save a backup of your working web.config
4. Try adding your "defaultDocument" section and see what happens.
5. If it still doesn't work, please cut/paste:

   a) the exact section (as I presume you did above)

   b) the exact error message

ALSO:

Q: It now fails in *BOTH* your MSVS2012 (running locally) *AND* your target web server, correct?

Q: Are you sure the target web server is ASP.Net 4.0 capable?

Comment: Cudos on the misspelling detection. Good eyes!

Comment: I did as you asked (no changes needed to be done) and made it work with the "fresh" version of web.config. Then i added the defaultDocument tag and got the message that i'll paste in in the next comment.

Comment: The element 'system.web' has invalid child element 'defaultDocument'. List of possible elements expected:

Comment: 'anonymousIdentification, authentication, authorization, browserCaps, clientTarget, compilation, customErrors, deployment, deviceFilters, fullTrustAssemblies, globalization, healthMonitoring, hostingEnvironment, httpCookies, httpHandlers, httpModules, httpRuntime, identity, machineKey, membership, mobileControls, pages, partialTrustVisibleAssemblies, processModel, profile, roleManager, securityPolicy, sessionPageState, sessionState, siteMap, trace, trust, urlMappings, webControls, webParts, webServices, xhtmlConformance, caching'. C:\...\Web.config

Comment: It also lists an error message which i mentioned in the comment below. It says: "Unrecognized configuration section system.web/defaultDocument. C:\...\Web.config" (the ellipsis is there for readibility reasons)

Answer (score 0):

You config looks correct but the error occurs because it cannot find the file that is mean to be the default document for all your website folders

So please replace "Defalut.aspx" with he correct spelling of the file in the below xml

```
<defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value=*"Defalut.aspx"* />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

Comment: That's definitely a problem area BUT i don't think it's the cause to my problem as the error message complains about the tag not being recognized, rather than the file not being found.

Comment: In fact VS states very clearly that "Unrecognized configuration section system.web/defaultDocument." plus i have corrected the spelling and the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, I know, but for anybody still with a similar problem, I don't believe this has anything to do with the spelling of the default page name (that will probably just give a 404 when it's accessed).

The real issue is that the `defaultDocument` section should actually be under `system.webServer`, not `system.web`.  See [defaultDocument Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690361(v=vs.90).aspx) for more info.

So your sample config file should look something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <machineKey/>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Defalut.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```